# How to change a List to a Dictionary having the values as Boolean

Tags: javascript, python, list, dictionary, big-o

I have the following code. In this case I have a Big O(n^2). How can I write this code in a better way using another Big O Notation? The code is suppose to return True if one value from the list matches one value from another, else it should return False.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 6, 7, 8]

def common_inputs(list1, list2):
  for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
      if i == j:
        return True
      else:
        return False


print(common_inputs(l1, l2))
```

I have an example but is written in JavaScript and can't understand that much.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array2 = [1, 6, 7, 8]

function commonInputs(arr1, arr2) {
  let map = {};
  for (let i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (!map[i]) {
      const item = arr1[i];
      map[item] = true;
    }
  }

  for (let j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (map[arr2[j]]) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't explained *what the code is supposed to do*. The Python code you provided always returns on the first iteration, that probably is a bug

Comment: Anyway, in Python, you would just use a `set`, which you should actually do in Javascript as well (a `Set` object there)

Comment: are you checking if elements of list1 are in list2?

Comment: In Python, you would just do something like `bool(set(l1).intersection(l2))`

Comment: "The code is suppose to return True if one value from the list matches one value from another, else it should return False." Do you mean if there are *any common values at all*? Or only if there are *exactly one*? That's what the second code does...

Comment: Actually your code is already O(1), congratulations!

Comment: Yeah. I tried the code below and it's not what I'm asking. If at least one value from the list matches one from the another it should return True. Doesn't matter how many values these 2 lists have in common - if we have l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8] -> it should return false, but if we change the 5 with 1, it should return True

Comment: Both the answers below are correct, and so was my suggestion above (I think georg's approach is more idiomatic, with `.isdisjoint`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python idiom to test if two sets intersect would be

```
intersect = not set(a1).isdisjoint(a2)
```

In javascript there's no such thing, so you'll have to loop the second list:

```
function intersect(a1, a2) {
    let s1 = new Set(a1)
    return a2.some(x => s1.has(x))
}
```

Comment: I always forget about `.isdisjoint`

Comment: Checking the intersection seems more straightforward, is isdisjoint the idiom because it's more efficient or for some other reason?

Comment: Can javascript do something like `a2.some(s1.has)` like Python would?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: no, because in javascript `object.method` returns an unbound function.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode well, the intersection operations necessarily has to create the resulting intersection, but  for me I think `not set(a1).isdisjoint(a2)` is more readable to boot and I would prefer it on those grounds to begin with. This may not be true if the terminology isn't very familiar, but basically, "not disjoint" is exactly what we are asking, of course, it is equivalent to asking, "does the intersection contain any elements".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, not building the intersection (or any set, actually) and being able to stop early is what I meant with efficiency. About readability: To me it's a double negation. The question speaks about "common" elements, and expressed with that term, "isdisjoint" means "no common elements", so it's "not no common elements". And this answer speaks about "intersect", so "isdisjoint" means "don't intersect", so it's "not don't intersect". And maybe if I knew Latin or whatever the word comes from, the "dis" itself would strongly look like a "not" to me :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I think a good argument could be made that the API should include each negation - "is disjoint" and "is intersecting". But I could understand if the implementers simply decided to make one. EDIT: But clearly, I should just thank my lucky starts that I can work with python and dont' have to settle for not having `Set` objects at all until 2015, and the in-the-wild idiom being "Just use an Object!".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think `a.intersects(b)` might look neat enough to overrule conforming to the "is" prefix of the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` for more pythonic way.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 6, 7, 8]
common = set(l1) & set(l2)
len(common) > 0
>> True
```